# Compare float2s for Equality/Inequality

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some C++/CUDA code in which I would like to compare two float2 values for inequality. Essentially, I need something along the lines of:

```
float2 cond = {1,0}
float2 *array = ...

while (array[0] != cond)
{
    Code...
}
```

The goal of my code is to implement some rudimentary handshaking between a couple processes that are sharing memory. I want one of the values in the array to serve as a ready flag, so I want to monitor its value. I realize there are other ways to implement handshaking between processes, but I need to implement this without making many changes to code that already exists.

NOTE: As others have pointed out, making direct comparisons between floats is never a good idea. However, in my case, no operations will be applied to the elements in question, so there should not be any problems. In the future I will definitely work on a better solution, but under my current constraints, this needs to suffice.

Comment: using floating point values for this seems like a particularly poor idea to me.

Comment: I understand that. No operations will ever be applied to either of the elements being compared, so it should not be a problem. All that happens is either it will be set to {1,0} or {0,0}. I know there's an infinite number of better options, but I'm working under unfortunate constraints right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
float2 cond;
cond.x = 1;  cond.y = 0;
float2 *array = (float2 *)malloc(array_len*sizeof(float2));
// initialize array values, for example:
array[0].x = 0;
array[0].y = 0;

while ((array[0].x != cond.x) || (array[0].y != cond.y))
{
    Some code...
}
```

I don't think this really has anything to do with CUDA, but it would work in a similar fashion in either host code or CUDA device code.

Perhaps you are asking whether it could be done by some direct comparison, e.g.

```
array[0] != cond
```

as you have shown.   It cannot (because the `float2` struct definition does not provide such defined operators), unless you provide some additional scaffolding or framework.  This additional scaffolding or framework would include comparison code along the lines of what I have shown in the example above.

As a final comment, comparing floating point quantities for equality is typically not recommended.  Usually the recommendation is to determine that if the difference between two quanties is smaller than some threshold, then they are "equal".  But that is really a separate topic from your question, and possibly your "handshaking" use case does not fit this model, which would normally be used when comparing numerical/arithmetic results for "correctness".